# file access exception that I can't shake

Tags: c#, io

I have a third party api that is dropping a file into a directory every 100 miliseconds.  Sometimes I can grab it and read it, but I am swallowing a lot of "process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" exceptions just to get one good read.  How do I stop this exception from happening?

Here is the code I am using.  I read that using "using" statements should prevent this error, but it's not helping.

```
string content = "";
string path = "C:\\output.txt";

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) 
{
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);

    while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0) 
    {
        content += temp.GetString(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `ReadWrite` when you just need to read?

Comment: Most likely the other API is still writing to it while you are trying to read it. This is a common issue (basically a race condition). Swallowing the exception and retrying is a common solution.

Comment: Might it be better to live with the exceptions, unless you have some other signal that the other process has finished writing the entire file?

Comment: "_I read that using "using" statements should prevent this error_" You misinterpreted whatever you read there. Using `using` ensures that your own code closes a file it has opened in a _timely_ manner, avoiding problems like _your own_ program forgetting and letting dangle open file handles (and it is therefore good practice to use `using`). Using `using` cannot resolve file access conflicts between your program and other programs...

Comment: Also, is this a text file? If so, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2 would be simpler and likely use less memory overall.

Comment: Find out if your third-party app does something like rename the file or copy it to a new location after it has finished writing, and only start reading the file after it has done that.

Comment: Try `File.OpenRead(path)`. Or copy the file first and read the copy: `File.Copy(path, path + ".copy.txt");`

Comment: @PhilM Swallowing the exception is causing issues with processing time.  I'm currently doing this, but it's causing the data presentation to be slightly glitchy.

Comment: @mjwills - forgive me.  I had the parameter set to Read instead of ReadWrite.  I was just trying different things out of desperation.

Comment: @RufusL - interesting.  I'll try that tomorrow.  Thanks

Comment: @elgonzo - Thanks.  Good to know.

Comment: @DourHighArch - It doesn't.  It simply overwrites the same file with the same file name every 100 miliseconds.

Comment: @nikotromus That is an "interesting" approach. Can you suggest that they create a new file rather than continually overwrite the same file?

Comment: @mjwills - I will ask them.  This may solve the problem.  If I'm having this issue, I'm guessing other client's of their's are facing the same problems.